# FFMPEG play an overlay video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, echo, overlay, shell-exec

Hello everyone,

I'm struggling hours on placing an image over a video (overlay) and to play the output directly in the web browser (I have FFMPEG installed on the server).          Here is what I have :

```
$output = shell_exec($command);                 
$image =  '/image.png';         
$video =  '/videoin.mp4';       
$saved_video_path= "";      
$i = "'";     
$command = '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i ' . $video . ' -i ' . $image . ' -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=10:10:enable=' . $i . 'between(t,5,10)' . $i    . '" '.$saved_video_path;             
echo "$output";
```

I would really appreciate your help !

Chris

Comment: Video tag aside, does this code produce a playable file? (ie: if you put the `$output` to server or hard drive)

Comment: Thanks again VC.One. Works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have FFmpeg installed on my server so I can't confirm this solution works.
 (It works for PHP-based `img` or `video` tags, but not tested involving FFmpeg).

```
echo '<video width="640" height="480" controls><source src="'.$output.'" type="video/mp4"></video>';
```

So with your code it should look like :

```
$output = shell_exec($command);
$image =  '/image.png';
$video =  '/videoin.mp4';
$saved_video_path= "";
$i = "'";
$command = '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i ' . $video . ' -i ' . $image . ' -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=10:10:enable=' . $i . 'between(t,5,10)' . $i . '" '.$saved_video_path;

//echo "$output";
echo '<video width="640" height="480" controls><source src="'.$output.'" type="video/mp4"></video>';
```

**Some notes** :

- Try using : `$output = shell_exec('.$command.');`
- You should **escape** your **filter_complex** double-quotes :

example...

```
$command = '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i ' . $video . ' -i ' . $image . ' -filter_complex \"[0:v][1:v] overlay=10:10:enable=' . $i . 'between(t,5,10)' . $i . '\"' . $saved_video_path;
```

- Try using double-quotes on the **ffmpeg path** only `$command = '"/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg" -i` etc.